Batch script adding ' ' with a loop for all lines
I'm struggling with a batch script. I can't add properly '…' to my lines in a UTF-8 encoded text file.
Here is my batch code:
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

chcp 65001

call temp.bat

rem Path to the text file
set "inputFile=%folder%\part2.txt"
set "outputFile=%folder%\part2_modified.txt"
set "tempFile=%folder%\temp.txt"

rem Check if the file exists
if not exist "%inputFile%" (
    echo File %inputFile% does not exist.
    pause
    goto :eof
)

rem Create an empty output file
> "%tempFile%" echo.

rem Read lines from the file, replace spaces with underscores, and add apostrophes
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (%inputFile%) do (
    set "line=%%A"
    set "line=!line: =_!"

    rem Add apostrophes to each element before the comma
    set "newLine="
    for %%B in ("!line:,=" "!") do (
        if defined newLine (
            set "newLine=!newLine!,"
        )
        set "newLine=!newLine!'%%~B'"
    )
    
    >> "%tempFile%" echo !newLine!
)

rem Move the first apostrophe after the first parenthesis
> "%outputFile%" echo.
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in (%tempFile%) do (
    set "line=%%A"
    set "prefix="
    set "rest="
    for /f "tokens=1* delims=()" %%B in ("!line!") do (
        set "prefix=%%B"
        set "rest=%%C"
    )
    set "newLine=(!prefix!'!rest!"
    
    >> "%outputFile%" echo !newLine!
)

rem Delete the temporary file
del "%tempFile%"

echo Replacement of spaces with underscores and addition of apostrophes completed. Result saved in %outputFile%.

endlocal

I use chcp 65001 because CMD was showing some artifacts when using Polish special characters. But if it's not necessary, I'll remove this command line.
call temp.bat can be ignored because it is just responsible for the definition of environment variables like folder with the appropriate specific location of the folder, etc.
File part2.txt has lines of text like this:
(3443,Y,Y,NULL); 
(3444,Ilość OSR/FJM,Ilość OSR/FJM,NULL); 
(3445,Niejednorodność dozwolona,Niejednorodność dozwolona,NULL); 
(3446,Nazwa drukarki,Nazwa drukarki,NULL); 

All lines begin with ( and end with ); and a trailing space. None of the lines have between the round brackets other brackets of any type. There are no values enclosed already in ' or " and all commas separate values.
File part2_modified.txt should have finally:
('3446','Nazwa_drukarki','Nazwa_drukarki','NULL');
('3444','Ilość_OSR/FJM','Ilość_OSR/FJM','NULL');
('3445','Niejednorodność_dozwolona','Niejednorodność_dozwolona','NULL');
('3446','Nazwa_drukarki','Nazwa_rukarki','NULL');

There should be added ' around each comma separated string and all normal spaces should be replaced by underscores. The trailing space at the end of each line should be removed in the output file.
File part2_modified.txt has the following lines with posted batch file:
(''3443','Y','Y','NULL);_'
(''3444','Ilość_OSR/FJM','Ilość_OSR/FJM','NULL);_'
(''3445','Niejednorodność_dozwolona','Niejednorodność_dozwolona','NULL);_'

This batch script is deleting sometimes some of original lines, for example this line from part2.txt:
(3446,Nazwa drukarki,Nazwa drukarki,NULL); 

It is looking like this in part2_modified.txt:
(''3346','NULL);_'

Or even sometimes like this:
(''3349','NULL

I tried multiple ways of changing the for loop and even add if statements, but still the result was the same or even worse.
I'm writing this script to automate some things and it must be flexible and as you can see it must include ' after first appearance of ( and before and after all , and before last );.
Can someone describe me how to do it because I can't move on with this?
When I was reviewing all my automation scripts, I found a bug in this code.
The reason for using a batch script is simple: My company wants me to do it with a file with .bat extension. I'll try to convince them to use a different language. However, I'm still trying to do it with a batch file.

Here's what I've done to achieve my goal,
I've removed this line of code:
chcp 65001

And changed a little bit for loop:
rem Read lines from the file, replace spaces with underscores, and add apostrophes
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("%inputFile%") do (
    set "line=%%A"
    set "line=!line: =_!"
    
    rem Remove the trailing space and ); at the end
    set "line=!line:); =!"

    rem Add apostrophes to each element before the comma
    set "newLine="
    set "line=!line:)=!"
    set "line=!line:(=!"

    for %%B in ("!line:,=" "!") do (
        if defined newLine (
            set "newLine=!newLine!,"
        )
        set "newLine=!newLine!'%%~B'"
    )

    rem Add the parentheses back
    set "newLine=('!newLine:~1!');"

    >> "%tempFile%" echo !newLine!
)

When I run this script, part2_modified.txt includes:
('3446','Nazwa_drukarki','Nazwa_drukarki','NULL;_'';);

But when you add this line of code:
set "line=!line:;_'';);=');_!"

This is the final result:
('3446','Nazwa_drukarki','Nazwa_drukarki','NULL');


The following batch file would be more efficient for producing the expected output.
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem This batch file defines the environment variable folder.
call "%~dp0temp.bat"

rem Path to the text file
set "inputFile=%folder%\part2.txt"
set "outputFile=%folder%\part2_modified.txt"

rem Check if the file exists
if not exist "%inputFile%" (
    echo File "%inputFile%" does not exist.
    pause
    exit /B 1
)

rem Read lines from the file, get just the string between the
rem parentheses, replace all spaces by underscores, add apostrophes
rem around the comma separated strings and output the reformatted
rem line with the parentheses and the semicolon at the end.
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(for /F "usebackq delims=()" %%L in ("!inputFile!") do (
    set "line=%%L"
    set "line=!line: =_!"
    set "#="
    for %%B in (!line!) do (
        if defined # set "#=!#!,"
        set "#=!#!'%%B'"
    )
    echo (!#!^);
))>"!outputFile!"
endlocal

echo Replacement of spaces with underscores and addition of apostrophes completed.
echo Result saved in: "%outputFile%"
endlocal

The main difference is not using >>"%outputFile%" inside the FOR loop because of that results for each line to write into the output file in:

opening the output file on already existing or creating it on not existing,
seeking to the end of the file,
appending the line output by echo to the file,
flushing the file buffer and
closing the file.

The Windows file caching helps making these file operations faster, but better is the code above which creates the output file new in any case before execution of FOR begins with opening the input file. The output file is opened now all the time as long as FOR is processing the lines of the output file. Each line output by echo at bottom of the FOR command block is appended to the file buffer and flushed. The output file is closed finally on FOR finished processing the lines of the input file. The number of file operations on output file is reduced dramatically by using this code with ( and ) around the entire FOR command line and `>"!outputFile!" for redirecting everything written to STDOUT by any command inside the FOR loop to the file.
Another advantage of this code is that now other process gets the chance for opening the output file between appending two lines which could prevent cmd.exe opening the output file for appending the next line resulting in one or more lines missing in output file.
Which process could open the output file on cmd.exe always closing the file after appending a line?
An antivirus respectively file protection process could do that although most of these applications wait a certain time after a file close of a file opened before for write operations before opening the file and scanning it for malicious threats.
Delayed variable expansion is enabled only for processing the lines in input file which cannot contain lines with ! for that reason. That is okay here because of the format of the lines in the input file is well known. The file and folder names can contain one or more exclamation marks like on definition of the variable outputFile with:
set "outputFile=%folder%\Development & Test 100%% (!).txt"

The outer FOR /F loop uses ( and ) as delimiters to get just the string between them assigned to the loop variable L which is assigned next to the environment variable line. The semicolon and the trailing space at the end of each line is already ignored therefore by FOR on reading the lines from the input file. That makes processing of the lines faster as less string substitutions are needed to get the expected output.
The most often needed environment variable newLine is renamed to # which results in having this environment variable with vary short name always at top of the environment variables list which improves also the efficiency of the batch file during the execution. It does not make a noticeable difference on running the batch file with an input file containing just four lines, but it makes a difference on input file contains 500.000 lines, 5 minutes and 17,77 seconds with # versus 5 minutes and 42,40 seconds with newLine on my current PC.
The line with all spaces replaced by underscores can be directly processed by the inner FOR loop which interprets normal space, horizontal tab, comma, semicolon, equal sign and OEM encoded no-break space (byte with hexadecimal value FF) as delimiters. The inner FOR loop must be as follows if there is a byte with hexadecimal value 3B (semicolon) or 3D (equal sign) which should not be interpreted as delimiter.
    for %%B in ("!line:,=" "!") do (
        if defined # set "#=!#!,"
        set "#=!#!'%%~B'"
    )

A byte with hexadecimal value FF cannot exist in a UTF-8 encoded file (on being a valid UTF-8 encoded file).
